# append integer with comma in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function that assigns a number to a variable, and then append this number as an integer in a list. The numbers assigned may or may not have a comma.

```
for number in values:
    list_of_values.append(int(number))

#do a few calculations for some of the numbers in the list
```

But this will just create a list where each number is rounded to a integer. How can I append the number as an integer and still retain its "true" value, without it being rounded?

edit:

sample values:
"0", "2", "1.5", "0.5", ...

Comment: If it's true value is not an integer, then use `float()` to represent real numbers. Can you give us a *sample* of the input?

Comment: I have tried "list_of_values.append(int(float(number)))", but it still rounds the value. I will edit the question with a sample

Comment: That is because *integers* are not *real numbers*. Remove the `int()`!

Comment: By definition, an integer doesn't have a comma and trailing digits. It's only integer. Besides, it's not a comma, it's a point what separates the integer part from the decimal part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to represent [real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) (numbers with decimals behind a decimal point, or, in some locales, after the comma), then you should not use `int()` to represent these.

Use [`float()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) or [`decimal.Decimal()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) to represent the numbers instead:

```
list_of_values.append(float(number))
```

`int()` represents the number as an [integer number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_number), which **by definition** do not have a decimal component. If you don't want rounded numbers, don't use integers.

Whether you pick `float()` or `decimal.Decimal()` depends on your precision and performance needs. `float()` arithmetic can be handled in CPU hardware but are less precise (decimals are approximated using binary fractions), `decimal.Decimal()` preserves precision but arithmetic is slower.

Answer (score 2):

the integer datatype is not able to hold floating values!
therefore you could use the float datatype instead!

```
list_of_values.append(float(number))
```